# how to pass an array of variable in json and retrieve it

Tags: php, mysql, json, zend-framework

i got a array named in a variable $coinPacks and i tried to pass it like this

---

```
echo $this->_helper->json(array('pack'=>$coinPacks));
```

---

but getting nothing when i use this code to display it

---

```
 alert(JSON.stringify(response.pack));
```

---

how can i pass the value and retrieve it

---

when i print the variable $CoinPacks i get a response just like this

[_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [number_of_coins] => 100
                    [price] => 1.00
                )

```
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [number_of_coins] => 500
                [price] => 3.00
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [number_of_coins] => 1000
                [price] => 5.00
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [number_of_coins] => 5000
                [price] => 10.00
            )

    )
```

and also like some codes like these too

[_metadata:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [SCHEMA_NAME] => 
                            [TABLE_NAME] => packs
                            [COLUMN_NAME] => id
                            [COLUMN_POSITION] => 1
                            [DATA_TYPE] => int
                            [DEFAULT] => 
                            [NULLABLE] => 
                            [LENGTH] => 
                            [SCALE] => 
                            [PRECISION] => 
                            [UNSIGNED] => 
                            [PRIMARY] => 1
                            [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 1
                            [IDENTITY] => 1
                        )

```
                [pack_name] => Array
                    (
                        [SCHEMA_NAME] => 
                        [TABLE_NAME] => packs
                        [COLUMN_NAME] => pack_name
                        [COLUMN_POSITION] => 2
                        [DATA_TYPE] => varchar
                        [DEFAULT] => 
                        [NULLABLE] => 1
                        [LENGTH] => 200
                        [SCALE] => 
                        [PRECISION] => 
                        [UNSIGNED] => 
                        [PRIMARY] => 
                        [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 
                        [IDENTITY] => 
                    )

                [number_of_coins] => Array
                    (
                        [SCHEMA_NAME] => 
                        [TABLE_NAME] => packs
                        [COLUMN_NAME] => number_of_coins
                        [COLUMN_POSITION] => 3
                        [DATA_TYPE] => int
                        [DEFAULT] => 
                        [NULLABLE] => 1
                        [LENGTH] => 
                        [SCALE] => 
                        [PRECISION] => 
                        [UNSIGNED] => 
                        [PRIMARY] => 
                        [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 
                        [IDENTITY] => 
                    )

                [price] => Array
                    (
                        [SCHEMA_NAME] => 
                        [TABLE_NAME] => packs
                        [COLUMN_NAME] => price
                        [COLUMN_POSITION] => 4
                        [DATA_TYPE] => float
                        [DEFAULT] => 
                        [NULLABLE] => 1
                        [LENGTH] => 
                        [SCALE] => 2
                        [PRECISION] => 10
                        [UNSIGNED] => 
                        [PRIMARY] => 
                        [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 
                        [IDENTITY] => 
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
json_encode(array('pack'=>$coinPacks)); // check if it matches the output of your helper
```

This encodes the array into JSON.

---

JS

```
console.log(JSON.parse(response));
```

This decodes the JSON into a JS object (and outputs it to the console).

To get your pack info:

```
var pack = JSON.parse(response).pack;
```

Comment: now it is displaying "undefined " in the alert box. how can i pass the array using json ??? please help.searched a lot

Comment: What did you put into the alert?

Comment: alert(JSON.parse(response.pack));

its response is just like this

"pack":{}

Comment: Then something is wrong with the encoded JSON. See what PHP outputs.

Comment: updated the question, please check when i print the variable $coinPacks

Comment: That's fine, but what's the json-encoded output? If you're using the json_encode example I gave you, it has to work.

Comment: when i use Zend_Debug::dump($coinPacks); it showing response like this <pre>object(Zend_Db_Table_Rowset)#147 (10) { [&quot;_data&quot;:protected] =&gt; array(4) { [0] =&gt; array(3) { [&quot;id&quot;] =&gt; string(1) &quot;1&quot; 
[&quot;number_of_coins&quot;] =&gt; string(3) &quot;100&quot; [&quot;price&quot;] =&gt; string(4) &quot;1.00&quot; –

Comment: That's definitely not going to work because it's not JSON. See what it looks like either after when you process it with that json helper, or after json_encode I showed you.